# Remove password from git

Tags: git

When I change files and write:

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push
```

then git automaticaly pushes it to my github account without asking about username and password. I have tried:

```
git config --global --remove-section user
git config --global --unset-all user.name
git config --global --unset-all user.email
git config --global --unset-all user.password
```

but didn't help...
I have also delete folder with git SSH keys.
When I commit I get a message: `Committer: Xxx Xxx <xxx@xxx.com> Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname.` But this email xxx@xxx.com differs from my github account email...
Why still git recognizes password and username?

Comment: Are you using an ssh key? Do you want it to push to GitHub?

Comment: I'm not using SSH key becuz I delete thefolder containing it from my computer. Yes, I push it to github.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Answer (score 2):

Just using `--unset` instead of `--unset-all` worked for me to delete my password to put my new SSH token.

So `git config --global --unset user.password` and then any git action that requires credentials triggers the login with user and password again

Answer (score 1):

One of two things has happened:

- Your Git repository is unprotected and you allow anonymous pushes to it.
- Your Git repository is configured with an SSH key that is on your local machine.

If you want to *require* that Git ask you for a username and password, then you need to not use the `git://` protocol; simply using the `https://` protocol will address the issue.

To do this, [change the remote branches of your repository to https](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: Third option: a password manager stores the user name and password

Comment: 1. In another computer I must provide user.name and password when I want to push to my account. 2. I have deleted folder with SSH keys on my computer. 3. remote url origin is `https://` When I do commit I get message: ` `Committer: Xxx Xxx <xxx@xxx.com>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname.` But this email xxx@xxx.com differs from my github account email...